# Clickhouse Materialized DateTime column not showing time according to specified timezone

Tags: sql, clickhouse

So i have a table having DDL

```
CREATE TABLE test_for_date
(
    `insert_time` DateTime64(3),
    `mat_time_utc` DateTime MATERIALIZED toDateTime(insert_time, 'Asia/Calcutta')
)
ENGINE = Log
```

inserting the data to table

```
insert into test_for_date(*) values('1629185516555')
```

When i select the columns from table i should expect **insert_time as UTC** and **mat_time_utc as IST** but both of the column are showing UTC time.

```
┌─────────────insert_time─┬────────mat_time_utc─┐
│ 2021-08-17 07:31:56.555 │ 2021-08-17 07:31:56 │
└─────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

But when i run the materialized column's logic in a seperate query, it is giving correct result

```
select toDateTime(insert_time, 'Asia/Calcutta') from test_for_date;

┌─toDateTime(insert_time, 'Asia/Calcutta')─┐
│                      2021-08-17 13:01:56 │
└──────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I am not able to understand why is this happening. Internally how datetime is stored and how materialized column is executed.

P.S - Server timezone is 'Etc/UTC'

```
select timezone()
┌─timezone()─┐
│ Etc/UCT    │
└────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

The column `mat_time_utc` doesn't declare the timezone so it gets the server's default, which in your case is UTC. You can declare it with something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_for_date
(
    `insert_time` DateTime64(3),
    `mat_time_utc` DateTime('Asia/Calcutta') MATERIALIZED toDateTime(insert_time)
)
ENGINE = Log

insert into test_for_date(*) values('1629185516555')

SELECT
    insert_time,
    mat_time_utc
FROM test_for_date

┌─────────────insert_time─┬────────mat_time_utc─┐
│ 2021-08-17 09:31:56.555 │ 2021-08-17 13:01:56 │
└─────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```